# HMAC Authorisation for JavaScript (Vue) Application - where to store the private key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hmac

I am implementing HMAC Authorisation for a Single-Page Vue App. The basic workflow is as follows:

1. User sends a request with username & password
2. Server checks the credentials, and on successful login returns the public key & private key
3. For any further requests, client generates an HMAC using the request URI, data and the private key. The server generates a hash using the same data to see if they match.

My question is what is the most secure way to store the private key for the client? `localStorage` seems to be unsafe, and the Secure HTTPS-Only Cookies would work, but the JS has to have access to it to generate the HMAC for each request? What would be the best workaround in this situation?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? oauth might be better.

Comment: I did not invent HMAC

Comment: If the server generates the private key and sends it to the user, it's no longer a private key?!

Comment: What makes you think that `localStorage` is unsafe? From whom are you trying to guard the key, what is your threat model?

Comment: @Bergi in this context it's private as it's used for generating hashes, compared to the public key which is sent plain by the client with every request. Mainly all the answers on StackOverflow (and other network sites) makes me think that, and I am trying to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: @Giedrius It doesn't matter where you store the value if you fell prey to an XSS attack - the malicious code can do anything that your code did. You need to prevent XSS in the first place.

Comment: @Giedrius, did get the hmac auth from frontend(vuejs) or backend, bcoz i have also facing same issue. based on key and scret to create the from frontend side.